# In vuelidate use a label rather than $property in customizing validation messages

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Sometimes it would be more convenient to customize a validation message with a label rather than the property. For example:
Let's imagine there is a field in form named 'x' but the UI interface shows it as 'Name' (the field label). But, as fas as I understand, the customizazion of a validation message does allow only the use of properties, that is name fields.

```js
validations: {
    required: "The field {property} is required.",
}
```

Is there a way to use a label to customize the above message?
Thank you!